# How to change sign of a .BLOCK or .WORD in Pep8 (Assembly)?

Tags: assembly, pep8-assembly

How would I go about changing the sign of a negative .BLOCK to positive in Pep8? And the other way around?

Thank you

Comment: according to https://code.google.com/p/pep8-1/wiki/InstructionSet you should use `NEGr` instruction. However, I don't know more than Google. In fact, I heard about that PEP/8 just now :)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is load 0 into the accumulator, and then subtract the number by that.

```
LDA 0,i
SUBA num1,d
STA num1
```